# How can I get my "Replace Text" code working?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using NetSpell in my application in order to provide Spell checking. Everything bar one feature of NetSpell is working fine. This is the "Replace Word" feature (rather an important feature in a spell checker, eh?).

The code is as follows:

```
private NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling spelling;
    private NetSpell.SpellChecker.Dictionary.WordDictionary wordDictionary;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.Button spellButton;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox demoRichText;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components2;
    internal System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox Document;
    internal NetSpell.SpellChecker.Spelling SpellChecker;
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components1;
    internal NetSpell.SpellChecker.Dictionary.WordDictionary WordDictionary;
```

Launch Spell Check:

```
 private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no text to check. Spellcheck will not be launched", "No Text", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                this.spelling1.Text = this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text;
                this.spelling1.SpellCheck();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading Spell Checker. Please reload application and try again. " + ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Replace Word:

```
 private void spelling_ReplacedWord(object sender, NetSpell.SpellChecker.ReplaceWordEventArgs e)
        {
            int start = this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
            int length = this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionLength;

            this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Select(e.TextIndex, e.Word.Length);
            this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = e.ReplacementWord;

            if (start > this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length)
                start = this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length;

            if ((start + length) > this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length)
                length = 0;

            this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Select(start, length);
        }
```

Delete Word:

```
private void spelling_DeletedWord(object sender, NetSpell.SpellChecker.SpellingEventArgs e)
    {
        int start = this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionStart;
        int length = this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectionLength;

        this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Select(e.TextIndex, e.Word.Length);
        this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.SelectedText = "";

        if (start > this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length)
            start = this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length;

        if ((start + length) > this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Text.Length)
            length = 0;

        this.richTextBoxPrintCtrl1.Select(start, length);
    }
```

I'm stuck now as to where the issue is. Could anybody help point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

--EDIT--

I've added all the code that is used with the Spell Check feature. I'm sorry if this is incorrect, but I'm new to programming and I still don't fully understand all the technical terms, so I'm just trying my best to help you help me. :o)

--EDIT 2--

I've found out a bit more. The "replace all" function works to an extent. If I change a word and press "replace all", it changes it within the Spell Check, but does not change it on the form. Please see the following images for example.

[image: Before word is replaced]

[image: Once word has been replaced (using Replace All)]

[image: Still not changed!]

Comment: You did not state what the problem is...

Comment: I did. I said that the "Replace Word" feature does not work. Meaning that when the user clicks "Replace Word", the word is not replaced...

Comment: Yes, but that is the same thing as a user saying: "The program does not work!!! Panic attack". Asking a question here is mostly about that does not work. Please try  to explain WHAT does not work. Does the text not get modified at all? Does the text get scrambled? What is the function supposed to do? Just replace ONE word or multiple words? What happens if you run it through the debugger, is start and length as expected?

Comment: Oh.. Sorry. No, the text does not get modified in the rich text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created these two functions myself and tested them. They are working. You can call them from your event handler.

```
static public class RichTextBoxExtensions
{
    static public void ReplaceWord(this RichTextBox rtb, int index, int length, string newWord)
    {
        rtb.Select(index, length);
        rtb.SelectedText = newWord;
        rtb.Select(index, newWord.Length);
    }

    static public void ReplaceWord(this RichTextBox rtb, string oldWord, string newWord)
    {
        rtb.ReplaceWord(rtb.Text.IndexOf(oldWord), oldWord.Length, newWord);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example (in your answer) of your contents of your textbox, and the start + length + replacingWord in your event handler?

Comment: The text box content is variable (the program is a word processor).

Comment: I understand that, but I request a simple example in which it does not work, with those variables. Because I am starting to fear that your logic might be okay, but that the variables inside `e` are not correct.

Comment: I'll post the entire code for the spell checker. (Sorry, I'm new to programming, so I'm still learning all the terms.) :o)

Comment: I do not need the entire code... you four little values: the text, the start, the length and the replacingWord as your debugger shows it.

Comment: Okay, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the line that starts with `int start = this...`. You can set breakpoints with F9. Run the program until the breakpoint hits. Select the variable `e` and press SHIFT-F9 so you can see the contents.

Comment: How do I know if the BreakPoint hits? I tried running the "Replace" function and nothing happened.

Comment: Also, I've just found out that the "Replace All" function IS working. Just not the "Replace" function..

Comment: It never seemed to hit that breakpoint... The program continued as normal and nothing extra/new occurred. And the hit count for the break point says 0...

Comment: I noticed another thing. Your spelling control is called `spelling1` (notice the `1`). You eventhandler is called `spelling_ReplacedWord`. Is the eventhandler attached to the `ReplceWord` event of `spelling1` or is there another spelling-control? Is it even attached at all?

Comment: I've gone through and made sure they're all "spelling1" as opposed to spelling, but it didn't seem to make much of a difference.

Comment: It is not really about the name. The name can be anything. But it hinted me into thinking that your evenhandler is not connected to your even.  Start looking if there is anywhere a piece of code like: `spelling1.ReplacedWord += ...`. If not, you have to add it manually, preferable after when the spelling1-control is created. Your code should be: `spelling1.ReplacedWord += spelling_ReplacedWord;`

Comment: Could you explain the BreakPoint thing please and I'll try and get that information for you?

Comment: Sorted. Thanks for your help today.

Comment: The breakpoint thing only works if that function is called. Right now I bet it is not called. Can you give me the entire initialization of the `spelling1`?

Comment: You did it? What was the solution?

Comment: I made a mistake... I had tried to programatically create the event but I needed to create the event from the Designer (clicking the event and adding the code). Don't I feel stupid...

Comment: Well... both ways are good ways. By hand or by designer. But I am glad it works now. :)

Comment: Me too. And thanks once again for your help. I really appreciate it.